# Rails CSV remove column that have empty header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-3

I am receiving a csv file that has some blank headers but data exists in these columns. I want to remove the blank header and it's associated column in rails.

Sample csv

```
#report
,Code,Price,Orders,,Mark,
1,X91,4.55,4,xxx,F,23
```

What I'd like returned:

```
Code,Price,Orders,Mark
A91,4.55,4,F
```

This is what I have so far as there is also comments on the csv which i am ignoring.

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |output_csv|
          CSV.foreach("out.csv", encoding: "bom|utf-8", skip_lines: /^#/, headers: true).with_index(0) do |row, i|
            output_csv << row.headers if i == 0
            output_csv << row
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSV::Row's `delete_if` method https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-delete_if, something like:

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |output_csv|
  CSV.foreach("out.csv", encoding: "bom|utf-8", skip_lines: /^#/, headers: true) do |row|
    clean_row = row.delete_if { |header, _field| header.blank? }
    output_csv << clean_row.headers if row.header_row?
    output_csv << clean_row
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I largely agree with the [answer of arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773525/3982562), there are a few things that might go wrong. `row.header_row?` will always return `false`, since the `return_headers: true` option isn't set, thus leaving out the header. [`delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-delete_if) is a mutating method, so there is no need to save the result in a variable. This only returns itself so you can chain it with other methods.

The following would be enough:

```rb
read_options = {
  encoding: "bom|utf-8",
  skip_lines: /^#/,
  headers: true,
  return_headers: true,
}

CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |output_csv|
  CSV.foreach("out.csv", read_options) do |row|
    row.delete_if { |header, _field| header.blank? }
    output_csv << row
  end
end
```

Note that [`blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-blank-3F) is a Ruby on Rails method, but since you've tagged the question with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) this should be fine.

From the [`CSV::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) documentation (also describing [`CSV::foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach)) options:

> **:return_headers**
>
> When `false`, header rows are silently swallowed. If set to `true`,
>   header rows are returned in a [CSV::Row](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) object with identical
>   headers and fields (save that the fields do not go through the
>   converters).